# What is the meaning of "you might just see"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am reading an e-book about hypnosis a paragraph of that is as follows:

"2. (Primary mode: activation of visual system with imagery of relaxing scene.) Next I would like you to imagine yourself lying in a boat which is drifting peacefully on a river. (Pause.) You are lying on soft cushions. (Pause.) The sky is blue with perhaps a few small white clouds. (Pause.) Someone else is taking care of the steering. (Pause.) On either side you can see green fields with a few bushes (Pause.) And perhaps a few cows or sheep. (Pause.) You are able to relax completely as you drift along. (Pause.) There are some rushes waving gently beside the water's edge. (Pause.) And you will feel the boat is rocking gently with them. (Pause.) A little ahead there are a few ducks drifting along as well. (Pause.)" And ***you might just see*** a few lazy trout deep in the river."

according what I have found in the dictionaries - among them " https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/just"  I can understand that the word "just" mean:

1- You use just to say that something happened a very short time ago, or is starting to happen at the present time

So the phrase "you might just see" can mean "you might have seen a short time ago" or " you are starting to see"

2-  You can use just to emphasize that something is happening at exactly the moment of speaking or at exactly the moment that you are talking about.

So the phrase "you might just see" can mean " you might see exactly at this moment"

3- You use just with 'might,' 'may,' and 'could', when you mean that there is a small chance of something happening, even though it is not very likely.

It's an old trick but it just might work.

It may just be possible.

So the phrase "you might just see" can mean "there is a small chance that you see"

however at the first example "might" is after just, not before it.

4- You use just to mean exactly, when you are specifying something precisely or asking for precise information.

So the phrase "you might just see" can mean "you might exactly see".

What is the correct meaning of "You might just see" at the paragraph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"You might just X" can also imply the *possibility* or *promise* of something happening.  It's normally used with positive outcomes, something the audience might appreciate.  In this case it's part of the hypnotic suggestion that the cool, peaceful stream *might* (if you so wish) include some swimming fish, which adds to the soothing feeling of the vision.

Another common use of this structure is  as a form of *understatement* to downplay something which is actually very likely.

> And if you're good boy and behave yourself at the doctor's office, there **might just be** ice cream on the way home.